# Trying to do ANOVA on the PCs of PCA but get error message

Tags: r

Can someone help me understand why I'm getting this error in R.

```
pca1=prcomp(~Calrate+Caldura+Risetime+Faltime+Lowfreq+Highfreq+Deltapower+FreqmoduLowfreq+Freqmoduhighfreq+Dominantharmo, data=xdata, scale = TRUE)
pca1
x.new<-cbind(xdata,pca1$x[,1:2])   
head(x.new)

Console: 
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 367, 366
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cbind dataframes/matrices with differing number of rows. Your PCA output has one row less than xdata, check your xdata variables. It is odd that your PCs are one row short.